# Get phyiscal path from IIS Application ID

Tags: asp.net, iis

I'm trying to get the physical path of an IIS application from its respective (unique) IIS application ID.

I tried to do this using DirectoryEntry "IIS://localhost/W3SVC" but whenever I attempt to access it, I get an 'Unknown error' ComException. I'm on Windows 10 using IIS 10.

```
var iis = new DirectoryEntry("IIS://localhost/W3SVC");
Console.WriteLine(iis.Guid);
```

Running the above snippet as Administrator does not make any difference.

Comment: this might be helpful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22265585/get-id-of-a-website-in-iis-7-and-above

Comment: Thank you, ServerManager solved my problem and its more comfortable to use too.